# Parse a mathematical 2D function pattern

Tags: java, parsing

I have been thinking about the program that calculates definite integral of function defined at input.

Acceptable input would be a combination of "+,-,*,^" operators and "Sin,Cos,Tg,Ctg,Log" trigonometrical funcions, e.g.:

> 2*x^2+x^(log(5+Sin(x)+1)*x^5)/(Tg(Log(x)))

The only difficult thing is to parse an input string; such method is expected as product:

```
public static double customFunc(double x,...)
{
     return <client input>;
}
```

in my example:

```
public static double customFunc(double x,...)
{
     return 2*x^2+x^(log(5+Sin(x)+1)*x^5)/(Tg(Log(x)));
}
```

So,I totally don't know what should I go about... have you got any tips, samples, ideas or solutions?

Comment: This will give you lots of pointers: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=expression+parser+in+java

Comment: Wouldn't you also have to input a range for x?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc No, because customFunc would be passed as "pointer" to an integrating function which specifies range on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your own parser, I really recommend [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org).  It's a great parsing tool, especially if you want to have your own logic surrounding it.  There's a really helpful set of tutorial videos [here](http://javadude.com/articles/antlr3xtut/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I can give you some ideas.

You would have to parse the function string, and separate out the operators.

You could use a Map to map the operators to Java functions.

```
+ to +
Sin to Math.sin(x)
etc.
```

You would then construct the Java lines that would do the calculation in a StringBuilder.

Somehow, you would execute the Java lines you've created.  That's the part I have no idea how to do.